# wp redirect is not working or not redirect to actual URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to redirect with specific page i have tried by using `wp_redirect()` but problem is first it go to back end then after I click on visit site it'll go to redirect URL.

So I want it redirect only specific URL not go first backend it only redirect to specified URL.

I have tried following code but it's not redirect properly( it's go first backend then go to actual URL ).

```
if(!is_super_admin()){
    wp_redirect(home_url('/vehicle-repair-managment/'));
    exit()
}
```

What is better way for do this thing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function baw_no_admin_access(){
    if(!is_super_admin()){
       $url=home_url()./vehicle-repair-managment/;
       wp_redirect($url);
       die();
    }   
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'baw_no_admin_access', 1 );
```

What you get,Now try wp_redirect.

```
wp_redirect($url);
```

Comment: what is $url variable output?

Comment: try in private window

Comment: are you using plugin for redirect?As I understand you have allow user to visit page except super admin right?

Comment: No i am not using any plugin.

Comment: glad to help you.